# Not able to print the output as (name + grades)

Tags: java, arrays, string, parseint

I'm trying to print `names + grades`, but I can't somehow. I can try removing the grades then names are the only one that will print, but I need both names and grades to be printed at the same time( names + grades)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Input the Number of Students:");

    int totalStudents = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());

    String[] studentNames = new String[totalStudents];

    System.out.println("Enter the Student Names:");
    for (int j = 0; j < studentNames.length; j++) {
        studentNames[j] = in.nextLine();
    }
    int[] grades = new int[totalStudents];
    System.out.println("Enter the Student Grades:");
    for (int i = 0; i < studentNames.length; i++) {
        grades[i] = in.nextInt();
    }

    for (String names : studentNames ; int grades : grades) {
        System.out.print(names);
        System.out.println(grades);
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting idea.  Use `for (int index = 0; index < totalStudents; index++) {..}` and then index each element individually (ie `studentNames[index]` and `grades[index]`)

Answer (score 1):

If you can make sure that the array of student names and the one of grades have the same length (and you should), then you can easily iterate by index

```
for (int x = 0; x < grades.length; x++) {
    System.out.print(names[x]);
    System.out.println(grades[x]);
}
```

That said, since the names and the grades belong together (the grade of student a makes no sense with the name of stundent a), the object oriented approach would be to create a class that holds both together. Since you're obviously just starting with java I'd strongly advice to do it right from the start.

Answer (score 0):

First of all instead of calling `studentNames.length` and `grades.length` each time you can simply use `totalStudents` as it represents both `Arrays` length.

Note that `gardes` array should be of type `double` and not `int`.

Then after filling both `Arrays` you can use :

```
for (int k=0; k < totalStudents ; k++) {
    System.out.println(names[k] + " : " + grades[k]);
}
```

Or maybe you can use a `Map<String, double>` to hold respectively, `names` and `grades`, then it will be easier to print them using:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, double> entry : yourMap.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " : " + entry.getValue());
}
```